# IgnoreCase Finder Not Working with Spring Data Rest and Neo4J

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-data-neo4j

I am unable to coax Spring Data Neo4J (with Spring Data Rest) to ignore case with a finder method. Here's an example repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface WidgetRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Widget, Long> {

    Optional<Widget> findByNameIgnoreCase(String name);
}
```

This example will only find widgets by exact case even though I have the `IgnoreCase` keyword. I would appreciate advice on how to get a finder method to ignore case with Neo4J. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case specific keywords are not implemented in Spring Data Neo4j yet. But it is possible to use regex in a derived query method.

Define a regex finder method

`Optional<Widget> findByNameMatchesRegex(String name);`

and use it like this

`widgetRepository.findByNameMatchesRegex("(?i)paul");`

This is the only option right now within Neo4j to find strings by case-insensitive queries. https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/where/#case-insensitive-regular-expressions

However this might be useful to support the `ignoreCase` keyword within Spring Data Neo4j as a convenient access function.

Comment: We'll support "IgnoreCase" on String Properties in the upcoming release of Neo4j-OGM 3.1.1 with SDN 5.1.